# Bijective functions and cardinality

Tags: functions, cardinals

I have the closed sets $[0,\infty]$ and $[0,1]$.

Define $f(x)=10^{-x}$ from $[0, \infty]$ to $[0,1]$.

I have these two sets and I have to prove that they are equal. It was easy in case of open sets but I am not sure this function that I have defined will work for closed sets because both 0 and 1 are included in codomain. Please, can someone help?

Comment: So you want to show that the image of $[0, \infty]$ under the map $x \rightarrow 10^{-x}$ is $[0,1]$?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Yes. I want to know would it be correct because I am getting the intuition it might not be because I want to prove that the cardinality of both the sets is equal.

Comment: Hi @TsunadeHatake, welcome! I've formatted your question into MathJax. Please refer to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a tutorial in MathJax. I also encourage you to try pressing "edit", so you can see what I've done, and a have a play around with it. Good luck!

Comment: @Theo Bendit Thank you so much, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @TsunadeHatake No worries! It's worth learning. It makes maths look so much better, plus people on the site get a bit grumpy when it isn't used. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The function doesn't work since $\infty$ is not a real number and therefore the term $10^{-\infty}$ is meaningless.

However, it is not a problem to manually define $f(\infty)=0$, since $\infty$ *is* in the interval $[0,\infty]$. Moreover, since $10^{-x}\neq 0$ for all $x$, the function will remain bijection.

Comment: Thanks for your help.